# How to make a function that show the firt N elements of an array till the elements are greater then an constant

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So, i need to create a function that: Goes trough a array and check if the element is greater then my const; If the element is lower, the function will add a new element in the list (last element + 2); If the element is greater it will stop the loop and exibit the list;

I've tried to use `forEach`, but it only show the first result of the loop

My code:

```
let s = [5,7,9,11];
const m = 15;

s.forEach(function a(itens) {
    if (s.itens = m){
    s.push(itens + 2)
  }
})
```

Comment: What does the desired output Array look like?

Comment: I want it to be a list of the N first numbers  until the last element of the array gets bigger then the m constant, using my post as a reference, the output shoud be: `5,7,9,11,13,15,17`

Comment: the if condition will have == not =

Comment: @4AM why is there only 13,15, and 17 added? shouldn't 5 numbers be added since for 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 numbers are being pushed to the array? (as seen in my current answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. You need to conditionally break out of the loop (which means you need a traditional for loop) when your value is equal to m. otherwise push the new value `(s[s.length-1]+2)`.

```js
let m, s = [5,7,9,11];

m = 25;
const expandArray = (inArray, m) => {
  const s = [...inArray];
  for (let i = 0;i < s.length;i++) {
    if (s[i] === m){
      break;
    }
    s.push(s[s.length-1] + 2);
    // safety if s[i] + 2 never equals m
    if (s.length > 100) return "Giving up...";
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(expandArray(s, m), s)
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Qual deveria ser o código se, em vez de ser uma constante, fosse uma variável?

Comment: @Thiago I updated the code to make it a function that can be reused. An important note is the you have to spread the input array into a new variable; If you do not do this, javascript will add the elements to the original array.

Answer (score 0):

This is with the **strong** assumption that your input array is already sorted.

```js
let s = [5,7,9,11,20,25];
const m = 15;

const answer =  s.filter( u => u < m ).map( u => u + 2 )
console.log(answer)
```